# Global constructors and MSVCRT in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, constructor, msvcrt

What happens with the following code in a DLL ?

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> global_vector;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        global_vector.push_back(1);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

... if compiled with /MD ? The code called by the vector's constructor and push_back (ie memory management, exception handling...) lie in MSVCRT.DLL... which as far as I understand is not guaranteed to be mapped at this stage. Does it get special treatment ?

Comment: `vector`'s code is header-only; it will be entirely compiled into your module.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Not everything it depends on is header-only.

Comment: This is *probably* fine, but if you want to be safe rather than sorry, why not have a function that you manually call after DllMain to initialize the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oleglv/archive/2003/10/24/56141.aspx):

> In a nutshell, when `DllMain` is called, OS loader is in a rather fragile state. First off, it has applied a lock on its structures to prevent internal corruption while inside that call, and secondly, some of your dependencies may not be in a fully loaded state. *Before a binary gets loaded, OS Loader looks at its static dependencies. If those require additional dependencies, it looks at them as well.* As a result of this analysis, it comes up with a sequence in which `DllMain`s of those binaries need to be called. It's pretty smart about things and in most cases you can even get away with not following most of the rules described in MSDN - but not always.